# Why do faster (eg sparse) versions of Transformers focus on the query-key product?

Tags: neural-networks, time-complexity, transformers, attention

A lot of recent research on Transformers has been devoted to reducing the cost of the self-attention mechanism:

$ softmax(\frac{Q K^T}{\sqrt{d}}) V $,

As I understand it, the runtime, assuming $\{Q, K, V\}$ are each of shape $(n, d)$ has complexity $O(n^2 d + n d^2)$. In general, the issue is the $n^2 d$ term, because the sequence length $n$ can be much bigger than the model dimension $d$. So far, so good. But as far as I can tell, current research focuses on speedups for $Q K^T$ which is $O(n^2 d)$. There's less focus on computing $A V$, where $A = softmax(\frac{Q K^T}{\sqrt{d}})$ -- which also has complexity $O(n^2 d)$. Why is the first matrix product the limiting factor?